# Rename folder in Windows with Unique ID

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have to rename some images in a directory, but I need to be able to give them all a unique numbers.

So the folder names are as follows.

```
Drawer~Folder~TAB~Field3~Field4~Field5~Field6
```

Now Field5 needs to be a unique number, is there a way This can be done in Command Prompt?

Comment: Why not just sequential?  Between each renaming, `set /a Field5 += 1` and boom!  Unique number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script you can modify to do what you want.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "x=1"
:while1
if %x% LEQ 11 (
    set "FileName=Drawer~Folder~TAB~Field3~Field4~%x%~Field6"
    echo %FileName%
    set /a x+=1
    goto while1
)
endlocal
```

As written it generates a list of 10 file names.

Comment: Delayed expansion problem.  `%x%` will always be 1 because it's in a parenthetical code block.  Easy fix would be to change your `if` statement to `if %x% gtr 10 exit /b`.  You could also use a `for /L` loop and get rid of your `set /a` statements.

Comment: @rojo I ran the exact code and it works for me on Windows 10 (but it stops at 9.) it has `enabledelayedexpansion` on line 2

Comment: Yes, the script does have `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, but it is not used by referencing `!x!`. Also, no space between x and = in the `SET` commands. It also needs to use `!x! + 1`.

Comment: @lit Thanks, I haven't used it much. I'm interested in trying rojo's for /L loop

Comment: @Marichyasana you're right about the expansion of `%x%`.  I just realized the `goto` breaks out of the parenthetical and forces re-evaluation without delayed expansion.  Sorry about that.  On a different matter, you should get rid of the `enabledelayedexpansion` flag if you aren't using it.  If `%filename%` contains any exclamation marks, they'll get clobbered if delayed expansion is enabled.  It's also a good idea to `set "filename=etc."` with the `"varname=value"` pair quoted.  This avoids problems with & and other special chars in `%filename%` without including quotes in the value.

Comment: @lit `set /a` doesn't require attention to spaces, or delayed expansion when referencing the variable by its name.  You can `set /a varname = varname + 1` in a loop and the value will be incremented.  Retrieval of that variable requires delayed expansion, but incrementing it doesn't.  In any case, I find assignment operators a neater option.  `set /a varname += 1`

Comment: @rojo - I agree that formatting looks better, but it comes at the risk of the user using the same technique on non-/A variable setting.